# PHPStan type aliases

Tags: php, generics, type-alias, phpstan

I have a PHP project which is a library for trees / nodes. It has several generic objects, all of which work in parallel - they are either ordered or unordered, depending on whether the children of a node need to be ordered using an integer index.

The children of nodes are represented in a collection.  And each node has a generic type for its "payload".  So in my code base there are a ton of objects that are typehinted in the php docs as (for example):

```
TreenodeAbstract<PayloadType, NodeType, TreeType, CollectionType>
```

It is a lot of typing (pun intended).

I feel that I should be able to use a global alias in PHPStan to represent the generic qualifications of (in the example above) "Treenode" but the type alias documentation in PHPStan is as little thin.  Any thoughts?

Comment: How much 'global' should it be? In the scope of a file, you could use a `@template T of TreenodeAbstract<PayloadType, NodeType, TreeType, CollectionType>`, for instance.

Comment: Project wide is the goal but I think you have a good idea.  Dunno yet if it is the best solution, I was thinking of how to use a global alias in the phpstan.neon file

Answer (score 0):

PHPStan supports both [local](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#local-type-aliases) and [global](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#global-type-aliases) type aliases.

In your case, a global type alias might be declared in the `phpstan.neon` configuration file as follows:

```yaml
parameters:
    typeAliases:
        AbstractTreeNode: 'TreenodeAbstract<PayloadType, NodeType, TreeType, CollectionType>'
```

Then, you can use the `AbstractTreeNode` type alias in your code:

```php
/**
 * @param AbstractTreeNode $node
 */
```

Note that you might need to provide the fully qualified names (see [PHP name resolution rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)) of the types in the type alias declaration in order to avoid ambiguity, e.g.:

```yaml
parameters:
    typeAliases:
        AbstractTreeNode: '\Acme\TreenodeAbstract<\Acme\PayloadType, \Acme\NodeType, \Acme\TreeType, \Acme\CollectionType>'
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work.  The type alias is TreenodeAbstractIFace: "pvc\\interfaces\\struct\\tree\\node\\TreenodeAbstractInterface<PayloadType, NodeType, TreeType, CollectionType, ValueObjectType>".  PayloadType, etc are generic types and are declared in the class-level doc block in all of the relevant source files.  Nevertheless, PhpStan seems unable to resolve them correctly when they are substituted in via an alias.  E.g. phpstan says something weird like 'method xyz has invalid return type NodeType' after analyzing the code.........

Comment: Yes, PHPStan doesn't seem to resolve the types within the value of the global alias. Neither does it resolve the template parameters in the local aliases, apparently(`@phpstan-type AbstractTreeNode TreenodeAbstract<PayloadT, NodeT, TreeT, CollectionT>`). However, local aliases could solve your problem to some extent, if you pass real class names instead of the template type variables: `@phpstan-type AbstractTreeNode TreenodeAbstract<PayloadType, NodeType, TreeType, CollectionType>`, then use it as `@phpstan-import-type AbstractTreeNode from \Acme\TreenodeAbstract`; `@return AbstractTreeNode`.

Comment: I think this is all true.  I'm waiting on some thoughts from Ondrej himeself over on the phpstan github issues area.  But I suspect the "best answer" in this case is local aliases and imports.